# Unique name for first level nodes in a PHP array to XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am converting an array to an XML file for a real estate listing.
I am almost there but I need the same name for each property node:
always  instead of the incremental key (<key_0>, <key_1>, etc.) that generates the script for arrays with numeric name .
I need to keep incremental key for sub-sub elements

Here my current code:

```
// the source
$data2 = wpgetapi_endpoint( 'whise', 'Annonces', array('debug' => false ) );

/* Outputs an array that starts like this where the first level below 
Array like here [0] or [1] should be converted to <property></property> in xml:
(
    [estates] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5346334
                    [address] => Kerkstraat
                    [area] => 200
                    [box] => 2A
                    ...
                    [pictures] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 41608035
                                    [order] => 5
                                    [orientation] => Landscape
                                    [urlLarge] => https://whisestorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/public/storage10119/Pictures/5346334/640/a2bea6c7a93f4c68a65146f2f5a000c5.j
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5346335
                    [address] => ... 
                    
sub-sub-level like [picture][0] should keep incremental (<key_0>, <key_1>, etc.) */

    
function to_xml(SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // if the key is an integer, it needs text with it to actually work.
        $valid_key  = is_numeric($key) ? "key_$key" : $key;
        $new_object = $object->addChild( 
            $valid_key, 
            is_array($value) ? null : htmlspecialchars($value) 
        );

        if (is_array($value)) {
            to_xml($new_object, $value);
        }
    }
}
        
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Biens_Kalliste/>');
to_xml($xml, $estates);


// print $xml->asXML();
$export = $xml->asXML();

$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.xml","wb");
fwrite($fp,$export);
fclose($fp);
```

It gives me this in the exported XML:

```
<Biens_Kalliste>
    <key_0>
        ...
    </key_0>
    <key_1>
        ...
    </key_1>
    <key_2>
        <id>5346336</id>
        <address>rue forestière</address>
        <area>236</area>
        <availabilityDateTime>2014-05-29T00:00:00</availabilityDateTime>
        <sub_array>
        <key_0>something</key_0>
    </key_2>
    ...
```

But I need:

```
<Biens_Kalliste>
    <property>
        ...
    </property>
    <property>
        ...
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>5346336</id>
        <address>rue forestière</address>
        <area>236</area>
        <availabilityDateTime>2014-05-29T00:00:00</availabilityDateTime>
        <sub_array>
        <key_0>something</key_0>
    </property>
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: I have read this a few times and am still no clearer about `"I need a unique name for each property node"` when in the example of `"But I need:"` - these property nodes are named `property` which seems sensible. Have I misinterpreted the requirement - can you clarify what the problem is

Comment: You're right, I will correct it for "the same name" for every property node.

Comment: Could you not simply do `$valid_key  = is_numeric($key) ? "key_$key" : "SAME_NAME";` ?

Comment: Hi thanks @ProfessorAbronsius, but as I just precised editing, I need sub-sub levels to keep with unique keys to distinguish from the main nodes for future manipulations.

Comment: What I was thinking was adding a parent foreach loop for [estates] first level childs and then loop inside each property with the current function but I am stuck on ideas and experience on how to do it.

Comment: OK - I see the use of the recursive function which I didn't notice originally. You could have a third argument to that function to track level in XML and whether to use `key_X` or `property` as node name

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorAbronsius, yes that's the other idea I cannot translate into code for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I received the solution by the Whise CRM developer, checking if parent key is numeric and null:

```
function to_xml(SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data, $parent_key = null) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($key) && $parent_key === null) {
            // Top-level numeric keys should be converted to <property></property>
            $valid_key = "property";
        } elseif (is_numeric($key)) {
            // Sub-sub-level numeric keys should retain their incremental keys
            $valid_key = "key_$key";
        } else {
            $valid_key = $key;
        }
        $new_object = $object->addChild(
            $valid_key,
            is_array($value) ? null : htmlspecialchars($value)
        );
        if (is_array($value)) {
            to_xml($new_object, $value, $key);
        }
    }
}
```